# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (gatsby and graphql)

Tags: json, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to connect my react application (which is using gatsby) to an XAMPP server that's running an instance of Drupal to perform queries using GraphQL. I keep getting this error about my config file which says:

```
error Plugin gatsby-source-graphql returned an error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here's my config file code:

```
 module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
   title: 'Gatsby Default Starter',
  },
  plugins: [
  {
   resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
   options: {
    typeName: "DRUPAL",
    fieldName: "drupal",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/graphql",
   },
  },
 ],
}
```

I've tried the localhost with and without the last "/graphql", just "localhost", and nothing's worked. I've restarted my frontend and backend server twice.

EDIT:
When I just go in "http://localhost:8888/graphql", it returns this:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"GraphQL Request must include at least one of those two parameters: \u0022query\u0022 or \u0022queryId\u0022","category":"request"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not your config file which contains the error but the service behind `http://localhost:8888/graphql`.
Probably it returns an HTML page (error page?) or XML content when JSON is expected.

Comment: When I just go in "http://localhost:8888/graphql", it returns this: {"errors":[{"message":"GraphQL Request must include at least one of those two parameters: \u0022query\u0022 or \u0022queryId\u0022","category":"request"}]}

Comment: Try to find out what your react application really receives. If it runs in the browser, use its network tab in the developer tools to see the result. It may depend on the requested content type, the exact parameters etc.